# How can I convert an inline pseudo YAML dictionary to a valid multiline one?

Tags: text-editing, parsing

Consider this code:

```yaml
- name: Cron set up
  cron: name=something something="anything" job="/bin/bash -c 'service=nslcd; [[ -x /usr/bin/$service ]] && systemctl restart $service'" minute={{ some_cron_minute }} 
  state: present
```

How can I change it into this:

```yaml
- name: File created
  cron:
    name: something
    something: "anything"
    job: "/bin/bash -c 'service=nslcd; [[ -x /usr/bin/$service ]] && systemctl restart $service'"
    minute: "{{ some_cron_minute }}"
  state: present
```

It's totally ok, maybe even preferred, if the code would work only for a single line instead of the whole buffer. I mean that I'll put the cursor on the `cron:`  line and use the created function to transform the line to the final YAML dict.

What needs to be done:

- new line after `:`
- every dictionary key has to be placed on its own line, indented by two more space then parent key (`cron:` in this case)
- key and value is separated by `=`
- there may be `=` in value too, like in `job` example above. But in such case there are always quotes around value.
- value may be in quotes
- optional: if value has `{{` text inside, put double quotes around

#### What I tried

I used to deal with this using a semi-working regular expression, but I recently lost it from history. When faced with challenge to write it again, I thought it might be much better to use some parser-like approach to this.

Most importantly - this is not only a similar case I'm dealing with and I would like to learn a better approach then regular expressions.

#### Background for this specific task

Some time ago it was possible to pass arguments to modules in Ansible on a single line instead of using a valid YAML dictionary. I went with that possibility because it was easier to search for patterns with `*Occur*` then with multi-line dictionaries.

Anyway these days this syntax is not recommended. And I have hundreds of files with the wrong syntax. I don't want to replace all occurrences everywhere. It is more convenient (and safe) for me to convert only single tasks when I'm changing something in them so I can test immediately.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info